# How to extract numbers with decimals from a string in scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Extracting numbers from string with decimals :

```
 1.8 min
```

How to get 1.8

```
replaceAll("\\D+","")) gives 18 string but not 1.8
```

Comment: Try `"1.8 min".split(' ').toList.flatMap(v => Try(v.toDouble).toOption)`. It will produce  `List(1.8)`

Answer (score 3):

Your `Regex` is simply deleting all non-digit characters. However, the decimal representation of a number is not a series of digits, it is a series of digits followed by a decimal separator (`.` in the US, `,` in Germany, and so on) followed by another series of digits. There might also be thousands separators in there (`,` in the US, `.` or a thin non-breaking space in Germany, `'` in some other countries, and so on). Also, the decimal part might be optional.

You have to decide how many of those complexities you want to handle.

Let's go for an intermediate one: optional decimal part, no thousands separators:

```scala
private final val decimal = """(?<value>\d+[.,]?\d*)""".r.unanchored

"1,8 min" match { 
  case decimal(value) => BigDecimal(value.replace(",", "."))
  case _              => BigDecimal(0)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regexp only matches digits without a dot, it can be fixed as follows:

```
scala> "1.8 min".replaceAll("\\D+\\.?\\D+","")
res0: String = 1.8
```

`\\.?` means that there may or may not be a dot

Also you can parse without using regexp:

```
scala> "1.8 min".split(' ').toList.flatMap(v => Try(v.toDouble).toOption)
res1: List[Double] = List(1.8)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Regex with pattern matching

```
def findDecimal(s: String) ={

  import scala.util.matching.Regex
  val decimalPattern:Regex = "\\d*\\.?\\d*".r

  decimalPattern.findFirstMatchIn(s) match {
    case Some(x) => x
    case None => None
  }
}

println(findDecimal("1.8 min"))
//1.8
```

Comment: It produces the result of `Object` type. Not type safe